# Why my JavaScript function won't end?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I have the following code, from which I expect the `x` function to return `null` after being called `3` times but it keeps returning the the same function:

```
const repeat = (n, tailFn) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tailFn = () => tailFn;
  }
  return tailFn;
};

const x = repeat(2, x => null);

console.log(x());           // function tailFn() { return _tailFn }
console.log(x()());         // function tailFn() { return _tailFn }
console.log(x()()()()()()); // function tailFn() { return _tailFn }
```

What am I doing wrong? See it on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENJEoO?editors=0011).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created a function that ALWAYS returns itself,

```
tailFn=()=>tailFn;
```

actually the loop is meaningless.Its behavior is similar to a recursive function without a base case.

Comment: Am I not creating a new function `tailFn` that is returning the old `tailFn`?

Comment: I think I got it. I just need to keep `tailFn` in another variable and return that from new `tailFn`;

Answer (score 6):

Your function just assigns `() => tailFn` to `tailFn` three times and then returns it. Instead, you should return a function which returns `repeat(n - 1, tailFn)` if `n` is not `0`, and `tailFn` otherwise.

```js
const repeat = (n, tailFn) => {
  return n !== 0 ? () => repeat(n - 1, tailFn) : tailFn;
};

const x = repeat(2, x => null);

console.log(x());           // () => repeat(n - 1, tailFn)
console.log(x()());         // x => null
console.log(x()()());       // null
```